# Why does the message sent using spidev change upon receiving bits from the ADC?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, spi, adc, texas-instruments

I am using the SpiDev module (https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev) to control a Texas Instruments ADS1261EVM on my Raspberry Pi (and programming in Python).

When I send a message stored as a variable, the xfer2 function seems to alter the message variable sent.

```py
import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
send = [0x20,0x0,0x0]
print (send) # to verify that the message is [0x20,0x0,0x0]
received = spi.xfer2(send)
print(send, received) # prints [received] [received]
```

Why does the variable send appear to be overwritten when received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug report for that: https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/issues/61

Comment: Good find! I had assumed it was something I was doing wrong the whole time.